# Using Spring @Transactional processiong only 8 threads parallelly

Tags: spring, transactional

We are using Jetty+Spring. My WebService HostService receives N requests in parallel (Logged the time as soon as request arrived to my webservice) but when tried calling Transactional add method, something similar to below snippet

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ClassA {
    @Transactional
    public Host add(Host host) {
        //logging time
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Now From code service I made the call to ClassA's add method, and logged the time, only 8 out of 100 request are reaching here at a time, and then when one finishes other starts.

I have already tries removing Thread.sleep with actual webservice call and a local process call, that doesn't help. But when I remove `@Transactional`, all requests comes at the same time to the add method, so problem is with `@Transactional`.

I want to understand

1. how `@Transactional` actually works, and why it limits to 8 calls in a batch, can I change this batch to some higher number.
2. All my classes are of scope prototype, so on what its trying to grab the lock on?
3. What should I do, to process all the requests in parallel, as my app in not db dependent it just calling other webservices(3), I don't need any lock, I just need the thread level lock, so that I can rollback if one of the webservice fails.

Comment: My guess you have a connection pool with 8 connections and because it takes a long time to finish the transaction (or you are messing around with connections yourself depleting the pool) others have to wait before a connection is available.

Comment: I am not using any connection :(. Just doing a sleep. In actual code I need to call 3 external webservices, and I want to rollback if any of them fails, thats why used @Transactional at method.

Comment: `@Transactional` with out any other configuration isn't doing anything. Not sure how many concurrent request handling threads Jetty has that might be a problem in this case. However just slapping `@Transactional` (or any other annotation for that matter) on a class doesn't mean it does something you will need additional configuration. Also in general you want a bean to be a singleton if the bean doesn't hold state there is no need for it being a prototype scoped bean (and I suspect that you are already using it as a singleton anyway).

Comment: ALso the fact that you aren't using a connection doesn't mean `@Transactional` doesn't need one. a `@Transactional` annotation will fetch a connection from the pool (or whatever technology you use).

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Spring, Deinum Can you please share how to configure connection pool for JPA, for non db operations. With this @Transactional my code is working as expected, so don't want to remove it.

Comment: If you don't need a transaction don't use `@Transactional`. What is it that you want to happen? Why do you think you need `@Transactional` for it.